# NPM registry alternative to http://registry.npmjs.org/npm

Tags: node.js, npm

unfortunately http://registry.npmjs.org/npm is down resulting in

```
$ npm install mime
npm ERR! Error: ucs {bad_utf8_character_code}: mime
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:177:16)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:81:20)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onMessageComplete (http.js:133:23)
npm ERR!     at Socket.ondata (http.js:1228:22)
npm ERR!     at Socket._onReadable (net.js:684:27)
npm ERR!     at IOWatcher.onReadable [as callback] (net.js:177:10)
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.38-8-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "mime"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rsi/projects/activiti.enricher/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

is there an alternative public repository, or any other way to continue working? Maybe using git clone for the dependencies?

Ralf

Comment: https://verdaccio.org/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There aren't any public alternatives, that I know of. At my company, we ended up doing an internal mirror, where we also publish our internal NPM packages.

I'm told it's not quite trivial - but definitely doable.

Comment: sounds interesting, maybe next time its up I can set up a public mirror. Did you follow any steps or guides when doing this?

Comment: I didn't set it up, so I don't really know.

Comment: You can use [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Repositories) - unzip-simple proxy of npm regisrty

Comment: There is working Chinese NPM registry: http://registry.npm.taobao.org

Comment: @mirik Looks like they are proxying to the main repo and they aren't hosting the files themselves. They are down at the moment just like the official registry.

Answer (score 12):

Update: Every URL in this post is expired, sorry

<strike>Just found this link that lists some mirrors:</strike>

http://blog.modulus.io/npm-mirrors

The listed ones as of this writing are:

- http://registry.npmjs.org
- http://registry.npmjs.eu
- http://registry.npmjs.org.au
- https://registry.nodejitsu.com
- https://npm.strongloop.com

Specify the registry when installing:

`$ npm install --registry http://registry.npmjs.org`

Or update the registry permanently in the config:

`$ npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org`

Comment: Is it just me or are literally all of the links dead now? :/

Comment: Wow, pretty crazy... Well at this point you can also use Yarn -- https://yarnpkg.com/en/ for a drop-in replacement to NPM

Comment: @groovenectar Yarn is just a client, it still uses registry.npmjs.org as the server where it downloads from.

Comment: @onlywei actually, yarn uses registry.yarnpkg.com

Comment: @MaximMazurok - which still relies on npm registry, at least for some packages.  Currently blocked because npm is down, but we only use yarn

Comment: There are some mirrors: https://registry.npmjs.cf, https://registry.yarnpkg.com, https://registry.npm.taobao.org. But the first 2 seem to be very simple mirrors because they fail when https://registry.npmjs.org fails.