# Is it safe to copy global node packages from one machine to another

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I am new to NodeJS and I need to install node packages **globally** on a machine which does not have internet connection.

I am thinking of copying the packages from **C:\Users\USER_ID\AppData\Roaming\NPM** path on my local box (which already have some packages installed globally) to **C:\Users\USER_ID\AppData\Roaming\NPM** on a remote windows 2012 server.

```
I have following questions:
```

1. Will copying folder like this would work? If yes, is there any potential risk?
2. Is there other way to install the packages on a machine which is not connected through internet?
3. I am using a windows 2012 server. Assuming copying global npm packages solution works, since I am copying packages under my userid, would it work for other users?

Comment: Following link talks about how to use other registry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383894/npm-registry-alternative-to-http-registry-npmjs-org-npm?rq=1